# Physical limitations on the charge density of a sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

In my E&M class, my professor asked us "Consider a sphere of radius R with charge density ρ(r) = αr^n for some integer n; What are the bounds on n that allow this charge density to be physically realizable?" I can't think of any reason why n should be bounded. I mean, there are certainly values of n that I wouldn't want to deal with, and I imagine in the lab setting that there is a limit to what we can construct. But, for an ideal textbook problem, I don't see any reason why n can't be any integer we want. Could someone offer some guidance/a new view point on this question please?

Comment: what is charge at the atomic level? positive or negative ions. Think ion sizes

Comment: Think $n$ negative.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically $n$ do not have to be bounded, because charge does not have an upper limit like velocity in special relativity. However in a physical environment you will experience a discharge if the charge density gets to large. This will be similar to the case where the voltage difference between the clouds and the ground is to big, and we get lightning. Maybe you can find this maximal charge density for air in your textbook or online and then proceed with the calculations.

Comment: the problem is general, in a vacuum there is no discharge.